# invalid literal for int() with base 10 :e, processing label in image path

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, artificial-intelligence

```
imagepaths = []

# Go through all the files and subdirectories inside a folder and save path to images inside list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False): 
  for name in files:
    path = os.path.join(root, name)
    if path.endswith("png"): # We want only the images
      imagepaths.append(path)
X = [] # Image data
y = [] # Labels

# Loops through imagepaths to load images and labels into arrays
for path in imagepaths:
  img = cv2.imread(path) # Reads image and returns np.array
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Converts into the corret colorspace (GRAY)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 120)) # Reduce image size so training can be faster
  X.append(img)
# Processing label in image path,
  category = path.split("/")[3]

  label = int(category.split("_")[0][1]) # We need to convert 10_down to 00_down, or else it crashes
  y.append(label)
```

I am facing error  while spliting , actually fetching image from folder 10_down and converting it to 00_down
how to solve this issue i am not getting it

Comment: try to be concise in questions, added code is great, but exact error details will also help people answer

Comment: `category.split("_")[0][1]` is not what you're assuming that it is. Start with printing it so you can see what it actually is.